# Why the need to say "von dort oben" instead of "dort oben"?

Tags: preposition

> **Von dort oben**, wo ich herkomme, kannte ich solch Herzenswärme nicht.
>
> {instead of}: **Dort oben**, wo ich herkomme, kannte ich solch Herzenswärme nicht.

---

In English, the inclusion of the preposition *from* seems strange, whereas in this German sentence, it seems you need to include *von*. I wonder why?

> = "**Up there** {uptown} where I come from, I have never had such heartwarming feelings."
>
> {not =}: "**From up there** {uptown} where I come from, I have never had such heartwarming feelings."

---

> = "I have never had such heartwarming feelings **up there**.
>
> {not =}: "I have never had such heartwarming feelings **from up there**.

Comment: Could you include a reference of where you found the phrase in question? It might be that in this case it's part of poetic or older language as indicated by _solch_ instead of _solche_.

Comment: @Tarok Hi. I seem to recall that this comes from a fictional story where people do talk in a rather old-fashioned way. Though, I don't remember much more than that. And yes. I was also concerned about the "solch vs. solche". But I concluded that this "solch" might be an adverb.

Comment: "solch" is a pronoun here as the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/solcher) tells us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation is messed up partially, and os loses connection to the *from*.

Both English and German know an idiom "to know/remember something *from* somewhere" - Which is what this sentence is saying - meaning "I didn't experience it there". You translated with "... I never *had* such feelings ..." which was a bit loose and, actually, slightly twists the meaning.

The sentence translates to

> From up there, where I come from, I wasn't accustomed to any such warmth of heart.

Also note that "von dort oben" doesn't necessarily mean *uptown* (In fact, in most cases, it doesn't). It could well be someone living in the mountains, or even "oben an der Küste".